# Variable not displaying (and adding) properly

Tags: javascript, html

Good day. I am practising my javascript skills by making a small calculator. The problem I have encountered is that basically the variable called `sum` which contains the user input and is displayed on the page isn't displaying properly. It starts from zero.

When I add 2 I get 02 as an output. When I add 2 again insted of 4 I get 022. I am posting the entire source code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Screw arround!</title>
<style>
    .btn{
        width : 50px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .btn2{
        width : 200px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .btn3{
        width : 200px;
        height:25px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <p id="asd"></p>
        <input type="number" id="textField" class="btn3"></input></br>
        <button id="add" onclick="compute(this.id)" class="btn">+</button><button id="subtract" onclick="compute(this.id)" class="btn">-</button>
        <button id="multiply" onclick="compute(this.id)" class="btn">*</button><button id="divide" onclick="compute(this.id)" class="btn">/</button></br>
        <button id="clear" onclick="compute(this.id)" class="btn2">Clear</button>

    </center>
</body> 

<script>
//----- variables
var sum = 0; // sum
var refr = document.getElementById("textField"); // get a referance to the textField

function compute(id)
{
    if(id === "add")
    { 
        sum += refr.value;;
        console.log(sum);
    }
    else if(id === "subtract")
    {
        sum -= refr.value;
        console.log(sum);
    }
    else if(id === "multiply")
    {
        sum *= refr.value;
        console.log(sum);
    }
    else if(id === "divide")
    {
        sum /= refr.value;
        console.log(sum);
    }

    //// set paragraph to the answer
    document.getElementById("asd").innerHTML = sum;
    if(id === "clear")
    {
        // make the values zero so new calculations can begin
        sum = 0;
        refr.value = '0';
        document.getElementById("asd").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `compute` function:

```
sum += parseInt(refr.value);
```

Or even `parseFloat` if you want:

```
sum += parseFloat(refr.value);
```

Note that `value` of input field is a string and `+=value` is actually string concatenation and not algebraic calculation

Comment: That is the answer. Thank you! I will mark it as the official answer after 10-15ish minutes (when the system will let me accept an answer)

Comment: Great! note that `value` is string and `+=value` is actually string concatenation and not algebraic calculation